# Return Largest Numbers in Arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Return an array consisting of the largest number from each provided sub-array. For simplicity, the provided array will contain exactly 4 sub-arrays.
I am getting output [27,27,39,1001] but the output should be [27,5,39,1001].

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  // You can do this!
  var largest=[];
  var gr=0;
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<=arr[i].length;j++){
      if(arr[i][j]>gr){
        gr=arr[i][j];

      }
    }
    largest.push(gr);
   }
 return largest;

}


largestOfFour([[13, 27, 18, 26], [4, 5, 1, 3], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Divide the problem into smaller problems and solve each problem on its own: 1) find the max value of a single array (put this logic in a function) 2) iterate over elements of array and find max of each (call function from step 1) 3) build a new array from the results of step 2 4) return the resulting array from step 3 5) profit

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is quite not right. To point out the error, see below.

Iteration 1

       ->gr = 0

       ->27 > 0?

       ->gr = 27

       ->push gr(27)

Iteration 2

       ->gr = 27

       -> 5 > 27?

       ->push gr(27)

Iteration 3

     ->gr = 27

     ->39 > 27?

     ->gr = 39

     -push gr(39)

Iteration 4

      ->gr = 1001

      ->1001 > 39?

      ->gr = 1001

      ->push gr(1001)


Try Creating a function with an array parameter that gets the largest number in that parameter instead of declaring a new for loop.

```
Array.max = function( array ){
    return Math.max.apply( Math, array );
};
```

Comment: *gr* should be initialised to [*Number.MIN_VALUE*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-number.min_value) or maybe *NaN* as the arrays might contain negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```js
var data = [[13, 27, 18, 26], [4, 5, 1, 3], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]];
var maxArr = data.map(function(item){
  return Math.max.apply(null,item)
});

document.write(maxArr);
```

**Explanation of your code:**

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  // You can do this!
  var largest=[];
  var gr=0;
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<=arr[i].length;j++){
      if(arr[i][j]>gr){
        gr=arr[i][j];
      }
    }
    largest.push(gr);
   }
 return largest;

}

var r = largestOfFour([[13, 27, 18, 26], [4, 5, 1, 3], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
document.write(r)
```

You code works file, but the issue is with `var gr=0;`. This is initialized outside the `for loop`, so its comparing largest number of first array with second and since `27>5` is false, it is assigning 27 only.

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  // You can do this!
  var largest = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var gr = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j <= arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j] > gr) {
        gr = arr[i][j];
      }
    }
    largest.push(gr);
  }
  return largest;

}

var r = largestOfFour([
  [13, 27, 18, 26],
  [4, 5, 1, 3],
  [32, 35, 37, 39],
  [1000, 1001, 857, 1]
]);
document.write(r)
```

You need to reset this value of `gr` for every iteration, hence, it should be initialized inside loop.

Comment: Simply posting code doesn't really help. The OP has issues with their logic, so you need to explain why they're having their issue and how to fix it.

Comment: @RobG Thanks for pointing it. Have explained the issue and another resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is right but you need put var gr=0; inside first for loop:

```
 function largestOfFour(arr) {
  // You can do this!
  var largest=[];
   for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    var gr=0;
    for(var j=0;j<=arr[i].length;j++){
      if(arr[i][j]>gr){
        gr=arr[i][j];

      }
    }
    largest.push(gr);
   }
 return largest;
}

largestOfFour([[13, 27, 18, 26], [4, 5, 1, 3], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var results = [];
  for (var n in arr) {
      var largestNumber = 0;
      for (var num in arr[n]) {
          if (arr[n][num] > largestNumber) {
              largestNumber = arr[n][num];
         }
     }
    results[n] = largestNumber;
    }
  return results;
    }

largestOfFour([[4, 9, 1, 3], [13, 35, 18, 26], [32, 35, 97, 39], [1000000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Even-though, it looks like a test question and not having a clear question. I am going to go ahead and help you out.

```
var arr = [[13, 27, 18, 26], [4, 5, 1, 3], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]];
var res = [];
arr.forEach(function(val, ix){
var sub = val;
var large = 0;
for(var i=0;i<sub.length;i++){
  if(sub[i] > large){
  large = sub[i];
 }
}
 res.push(large);
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jeremyrajan/hted9eg5/

if you look at the code, I am using forEach(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop through array and collect the subarray. And then running a for-loop through the elements to find the max number.

The only difference being that, I used forEach in my case to make things a bit prettier.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Using forEach doesn't make it look any prettier, but uglier.

Comment: What happens when a sub array contains all negative numbers, Jeremy? Also, using [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is far more elegant. `let largest = (...arrays) => arrays.map(array => Math.max.apply(Math, array));`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaner way to do it, but it's relatively slow if you care about fast.

```
function get_array_of_largest(rank2Array){
  var newArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < rank2Array.length; i ++){
    newArray.push(rank2Array[i].slice().sort(function(a, b){return a < b;})[0]);
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

`.slice()` copies a portion of an array. Since no arguments were given, it copies the whole thing.
`.sort()` sorts an array according to a function. Given the function I've sorted using, it sorts the array in descending order (element 0 is thus the greatest).

The reason yours is not working is that you're not resetting `gr` to 0 after you push the element.

Comment: Not my down vote (it's really annoying to get down votes without an explanation), but sorting modifies the original arrays and is inefficient here.

Answer (score 0):

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var newArr=[];
  for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
     var num=Math.max.apply(null,arr[i]);    
     newArr.push(num);
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

The following function uses Function.prototype.apply() to find the maximum element in a numeric array. getMaxOfArray([1, 2, 3]) is equivalent to Math.max(1, 2, 3), but you can use getMaxOfArray() on programmatically constructed arrays of any size.

```
function getMaxOfArray(numArray) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, numArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    return arr.map(x => x.sort((a, b) => b - a)[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that junior level like me might find easier to understand.

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {

// We need a way new array that would store the largest number as required.

  let newArr = []

  // We need a way to traverse through the subArrays
  for (let i=0;i<arr.length; i++)
  {
    // We need to find max in each sub array and add to newArr
    newArr.push(Math.max(...arr[i]))
  }
  console.log(newArr) // Check if its the answer we expect
  return newArr;
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, map and reduce together as a solution can be used.

1. The array is mapped
2. Found the largest numbers in the mapped array lists with reduce function

   ```
    function lgArry (arr) {
       return arr.map(function(sub){
           return sub.reduce(function(a,b){
               return a > b ? a : b;

           })
       })
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This of your input purely as a matrix.

Now, you can spread the rows of the matrix into a function that takes varargs. These functions capture the arguments into an array and send them into a reducer.

```js
const
  avg = (...arr) => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / arr.length,
  avgPerRow = (...matrix) => matrix.map(row => avg(...row)),
  minPerRow = (...matrix) => matrix.map(row => Math.min(...row)),
  maxPerRow = (...matrix) => matrix.map(row => Math.max(...row)); 

let matrix = [
    [13, 27, 18, 26],
    [4, 5, 1, 3],
    [32, 35, 37, 39],
    [1000, 1001, 857, 1]
  ],
  averageOfFour = avgPerRow(...matrix),
  smallestOfFour = minPerRow(...matrix),
  largestOfFour = maxPerRow(...matrix);

console.log(...smallestOfFour); // [ 13 , 1    , 32    ,    1    ]
console.log(...averageOfFour);  // [ 21 , 3.25 , 35.75 ,  714.75 ]
console.log(...largestOfFour);  // [ 27 , 5    , 39    , 1001    ]
```